# Imprimir fichero HTML en Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando imprimir un fichero html desde python, pero no hay manera.

He probado con `os.startfile(r"%s.html" % (group), "print")`, pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

> OSError: [WinError 1155] No hay ninguna aplicación asociada con el archivo especificado para esta operación: 'filename.html'

También he intentado lo siguiente:

```
win32api.ShellExecute(
        0,
        "printto",
        "%s.html" % (group),
        '"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter(),
        ".",
        0
    )
```

Pero me da este error:

> pywintypes.error: (31, 'ShellExecute', 'Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona.')

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

para poder imprimir un fichero `html` primeramente es necesario leerlo, de esta manera:

```
import codecs
file = codecs.open("C:\\Users\\angogi\\Desktop\\file.html","r","utf-8")
print(file.read())
```

Resultado:

*C:\Users\angogi\Desktop>python html.py*

```
<html><body><p>Hola angogi<p></body></html>
```

Comment: Creo que se referia literalmente a imprimirlo con una impresora

Comment: jajaja, pues si es asi no tengo impresora para probarlo. que hago con mi respuesta la borro?

Comment: Sí, me refería literalmente por la impresora